# Class members vs object variables of subclass

Tags: java

Below is the code snippet and its output -

```
class Box{
        int height = 1;
        int length = 1;
        int width = 1;

        Box(int h, int l, int w){
                this.height = h;
                this.length = l;
                this.width = w;
        }

        int volume(){
                return this.height * this.length * this.width;
        }

}

class BoxWeight extends Box{
        int height = 99;
        int length = 99;
        int width = 99;
        int mass;

        BoxWeight(int h, int l, int w, int m) {
                super(h, l, w);
                this.mass = m;
        }

        int volume(){
                return this.height * this.length * this.width;
        }
}
public class BoxDemo {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                Box b = new Box(10, 20, 30);
                BoxWeight bw = new BoxWeight(40, 50, 60, 10);
                System.out.println(bw.height);
                System.out.println(bw.length);
                System.out.println(bw.width);
                //b = bw;
                //System.out.println(b.volume());

        }

}
```

Output

```
99
99
99
```

Here i am not able to get why object bw is printing values initialized as class members. Why object bw is not holding values assigned through constructor?

Comment: actually ultimate aim is not to print 40, 50, 60 , i just wanted to know whats happening behind the scene here. If anyone can put here some good read regarding this, it can be helpful. Which java mechanism working here?

Comment: when in BoxWeight constructor ""BoxWeight(40, 50, 60, 10)** is called which again calls **super** to initialize height, width, length i thought all initialization using super will be done on **this** means BoxWeight object which in turn will have values 40, 50, 60.

Answer (score 4):

The members of `BoxWeight` hide the members of `Box`, so you don't see the values you passed to the Box constructor.

Just remove this members from `BoxWeight` :

```
        int height = 99;
        int length = 99;
        int width = 99;
```

It also makes no sense to have the exact same implementation of `volume()` in both classes.

Answer (score 1):

Because `BoxWeight` defines it's own `length`, `width`, and `height`, the corresponding fields in `Box` are hidden. You can either remove the fields from `BoxWeight`, or cast to a `Box` as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Box b = new Box(10, 20, 30);
    BoxWeight bw = new BoxWeight(40, 50, 60, 10);
    System.out.println(((Box) bw).height);
    System.out.println(((Box) bw).length);
    System.out.println(((Box) bw).width);
}
```

Prints:

```
40
50
60
```

Answer (score 0):

That's how Inheritance is working. The last `@Override` counts. In this case it is the `BoxWeight`.